# Trying to upload file via spring-cloud-gateway and RestController

Tags: spring-boot, put, spring-restcontroller, reactive, spring-cloud-gateway

I'm trying to upload (PUT) a file over a spring-boot-gateway forwarding the request to a internal RestController (see DemoController.java). I'm able to read the data but the connection stays open.
The gateway routes are configured via application.yml.

The demo code and curl requests can be found at:
https://github.com/knottnhupfer/spring-boot-reactive-gateway-demo

Start the spring boot application and call:

```sh
curl --user user:secret -v http://localhost:8080/api/testing/README.md \
     --upload-file README.md
```

UPDATE:

In the meantime I'm able to read the file but the connection is not closed on server side. Is this a normal behaviour of reactive and I actively need to close the connection? I realized that wrapping it with Mono closes the connection but does not read the data anymore.

Currently the RestController method looks like:

```
@PutMapping(value = "/{value}/**", consumes = "application/octet-stream")
public  Mono<ResponseEntity>  putArtifact(ServerHttpRequest request,
   @RequestBody ByteArrayResource resource, @PathVariable("value") String value) {
   [...]
}
```

Thx in advance

/david

Answer (score 0):

#### Short Answer

Workaround for you is adding `-H 'Expect'` to the end of your curl command.

#### Details

It is about Http 100 Continue Status Code. It is used when there is a possible rejection by the server (maybe because file is too big), then client can ask first to the server if a request will be accepted or not. So both client & server will not waste their time in case of e.g: there is possible rejection because of file size.

When you send a PUT request, curl [adds](https://github.com/curl/curl/blob/9ad034e5a1b2d42acfdbea184736066782c6c635/lib/http.c#L2524) "Expect 100-continue" to the request by default (Also adds in POST too if the size is bigger than some threshold). What I expect in this case servers will respond with Http 100, but it seems like there could be an [issue in spring cloud gateway](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gateway/issues/1337)

Adding `-H 'Expect'` to end of your command means you as a client will no longer wait for HTTP 100 Status from the server to send your request. But it is still a problem and the root cause of it should be investigated. Probably because there are a 2 servers handling HTTP 100 (gateway + server), the client somehow hangs out. These are also mentioned in [this issue](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gateway/issues/730)